# Insert mutiple textbox array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I write the insert statement for the following type of scenario?

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="tbxt[]" />
<input type="text" name="tbxt[]" />
<input type="text" name="tbxt[]" />
<input type="text" name="tbxt[]" />
<input type="text" name="tbxt[]" />
 <input type="submit" name="dosubmit" value="Next" class="submitbtn" />
<form>
```

I tried like the below which didn't work for me

```
<?php    
    if (isset($_POST['dosubmit'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['tbxt'] as $tbxt)
    {
    for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
    {
           $doquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mylist(`itemname`) VALUES('".$tbxt[$i]."')") or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

Also, how can I write the array count instead of `$i<5`

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @Quentin - Yeah, I knew that. Will change it to MySQLi. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You even dont need the second for loop

```
foreach ($_POST['tbxt'] as $tbxt)
    {

           $doquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mylist(`itemname`) VALUES('".$tbxt."')") or die(mysql_error());

    }
```

Its recommended not to use mysql_* functions. Instead use mysqli_* or pdo functions.

Answer (score 0):

just one foreach will do

```
foreach($_POST['tbxt'] as $tbxt){ *insert values from $tbxt by query*}
```